# Automatically Import multiple csv file in a folder to mysql with php myadmin

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin

Can you help me to tell the code on the command line, 
How I automatically import multiple csv file to mysql in phpmyadmin and create automatically table too with the csv file?

Comment: U can have python script for do this..
You need to upload csv data to a my sql data base Am I correct

Comment: That is too wide question. it is not clear what is the console for etc.